# Trying to solve for the remainder of $a^q$ modulo $q$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a prime and $a$ be a number from $0$ to $q-1$ (not an equivalence class).
The elements $a^q$ are exactly the elements of order $q-1$ modulo $q^2$.

I'm trying to solve the equation:
$$a+2*\frac{a^q-a}{q} = c$$
modulo $q$. This is equivalent to solving:
$$2*X^q+(q-2)X = qc$$
modulo $q^2$.

This is a specific form of a Bluher polynomial so I'm hoping the solutions can be solved in some way.

A very similar question is solving for the "remainder" of $a^q$, modulo $q$:

$$\frac{a^q-a}{q} = c$$

**Can we solve for $a$?**

Anything interesting we can say? I've tried some stuff including Hensel and L'Hopital's rule on the expression $(x^q-x )/ q$. I wasn't able to solve for $a$ in any way. I'm reading more about the theory behind Bluher polynomials, so maybe I will find something. Is this somehow equivalent to a discrete logarithm?

Comment: You can use the following SageMath code (for example here https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to print some examples. Sorry, code formatting is not possible in comments.

p=0
while p < 20:
     p = p.next_prime()
     for c in range(0,p):
         sols = [a for a in range(p) if (a + 2 * (a^p - a)/p - c) % p == 0]
         print(f"p={p}, c={c}, solutions={sols}")

Comment: I don't even see a pattern for $c=0$.

Comment: The $a^q$ are the elements of order dividing $q-1$ modulo $q^2$.

Comment: The fraction $\frac{a^{q-1}-1}q$ is called Fermat quotient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient

Comment: "The elements $a^q$ are exactly the elements of order $q−1$ modulo $q^2$." Not so. E.g., for $q=5$, $a=1$ gives $a^q=1$ which has order $1$ modulo $q^2$, and $a=4$ gives $a^q=1024\equiv24\pmod{q^2}$ which has order $2$ (and of course $a=0$ should be explicitly removed from consideration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed in the comments, the equation in question for $a\not\equiv0\pmod{q}$ can be restated as
$$a + 2af_q(a) \equiv c\pmod{q},$$
where $f_q(a)$ is the [Fermat quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient) of $a$ with respect to $q$.

By fixing a primitive root $r$ modulo $q^2$ and substituting $a=r^y$, we get an equivalent equation:
$$r^y(1 + 2dy) \equiv c\pmod{q},$$
where $d:=f_q(r)\bmod q$.
We need to solve this equation for $y$, which would be a residue modulo $q(q-1)$.

---

Let $d':=2d+kq$ for a suitable integer $k$ such that $\gcd(d',q-1)=1$ and rewrite the equation as
$$r^y(1 + d'y) \equiv c\pmod{q},$$
and then as
$$s^{-z}z \equiv c'\pmod{q},$$
where $z:=1+d'y$, $s:=r^{-1/d'}\bmod q$, and $c':=c/s\bmod q$.
Finally, let $c'':=c' + kq$ for a suitable integer $k$ such that $\gcd(c'',q-1)=1$, $t:=z/c''\bmod q(q-1)$ and $g:=s^{c''}\bmod q$ to obtain
$$g^t \equiv t\pmod{q}.$$

---

The obtained equation corresponds to the fixed points in the discrete logarithm problem, which is studied in a number of publications, e.g., see papers [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401014), [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401013), and [[3]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-009-9339-2).